# Unique representation of a rational function as a sum of rational function with disjoint variables

Tags: calculus, algebraic-geometry

Let $R(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ be a rational function. We shall say that $R$ is "**addable**" if there exist $1\leq k\leq n$ and two rational functions $S_1(x_1,\ldots,x_k)$, $S_2(x_{k+1},\ldots,x_n)$ such that
$$
R(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=S_1(x_1,\ldots,x_k)+S_2(x_{k+1},\ldots,x_n)
$$
for all $x_1,\ldots,x_n$.

It can be shown using induction on $n$, that if $R$ is "addable", then there exist rational functions $S_1(x_1,\ldots,x_{k_1})$, $S_2(x_{k_1+1},\ldots,x_{k_2})$, $\ldots$ ,$S_r(x_{k_{r-1}+1},\ldots,x_{k_r})$. such that
$$
R=S_1+\ldots+S_r
$$
and each of the $S_i$ is **not** "addable".

My question: Does that representation is unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're suggesting is simply splitting $R$ into sum of rational functions based on the variables. And since a rational function based on **unique** variables, is unique, then you're correct I believe.

The explicit reason behind that is that if you define the space $F(x_1,..x_k)$ as the space of all rational functions over some field $F$, then the functions within are unique, and the addition of these spaces is a direct sum. (Intersection is empty).

Comment: Thanks @Eran723 for your answer but I still do not understand. For a start, what do you mean by "a rational function based on unique variables, is unique" ?

Comment: Also, I don't think that the set of addable rational functions forms a vector space. Hence, how can we use the direct sum argument ? Furthermore, what prevents both of the following identities to exist? $R(x_1,x_2,x_3)=S_1(x_1)+S_2(x_2,x_3)$ and $R(x_1,x_2,x_3)=S_1(x_1,x_2)+S_2(x_3)$   ?

Comment: A rational function $R(x_1, .. x_k) = P(x_1,..., x_k)/Q(x_1,..., x_k)$ for some polynomials $P,Q \in F[x_1,...x_k]$.
This representation of $R$ is unique because of $P,Q$. 
By uniqueness of the variable I mean that if we define $R2(x,y,z,w)$ as some rational function, and $R2(x,y,z,w) = R(x,y) + R(w,z)$ where R is the same but differing on the variables, is still a unique decomposition

Comment: Do you assume that $P,Q$ do not share a common factor? otherwise, they are not unique. For example, $1/(x+1)$ and $(x-1)/(x^2-1)$. Can you write a more detailed proof of the uniqueness claim? Thanks

Comment: Yes, Like the rationals, I assume a redacted form. (In the same manner that 1/2 = 2/4).
A sketch of a proof is to assume that $P/Q  = R/S$ for some polynomials $P,Q,R,S$ such that the fractions are in redacted form, and to look at the multiplication: $P(x)*S(x) = R(x)*Q(x)$. By looking at the coefficients (starting from the highest and lowest), you can deduce uniqueness. This works because of the redacted form - same as it does in the rationals. (Both fields (as rings) share the same properties hence act very similarly for example both have prime elements).

Comment: Thanks Eran, but I meant an elaborate proof for the uniqueness of sum representation.

Comment: Lets say $R2(x,y) = x^2+y^2$ then we can pick $P(t) = t^2$ and have a decomposition: $R2(x,y) = P(x) + P(y)$. My point is that even that it is the same polynomial, the variables makes it different, since the space $F[x] \bigoplus F[y] \subseteq F[x,y]$ is directly summed and is contained in the overall space. Your "addable" functions are *exactly* this sum.
Within each space, P is uniquely represented, hence the representation is unique.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are looking at a specific subspace, such as $V=F(x_1,x_2)+F(x_3,x_4)$. Clearly, $V$ is a direct sum, so every function in it has a unique representation as a sum of each. But Shouldn't we be looking at all the subspaces $V_1=F(x_1)+F(x_2,x_3,x_4)$, $V_2=F(x_1,x_2)+F(x_3,x_4)$ and $V_3=F(x_1,x_2,x_3)+F(x_4)$? Are these subspaces disjoint?

Comment: They are not disjoint, rather that their intersection does not satisfy your property.
Notice that $R(x,y,z)$ cannot be decomposed to both $P1(x) + Q1(y,z)$ and $P2(x,y) + Q2(z)$, since if they were equal, you would find that the coefficients of Y are trivial or something of the sort. Anyhow that variable decomposition is strong.

Take for example: $R(x,y,z) = xy + z$

Comment: Thanks Eran. TODA (: